# Can i add more colors in tx_gridelements

Tags: typo3

i want to add more backend colors in Typo3 Gridelements.

Under Typo3 -> List -> CE Backend Layout  is an Option "Frame" with 4 colors and i want to add more colors.

[image]

Is there a way for it?

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use something like this in your pageTS:

```
TCEFORM.tx_gridelements_backend_layout{
  frame{
    addItems{
      10 = unicorn-pink
    }
  }
}
```

You can change every field from every table with this method.
See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/PageTsconfig/TCEform/Index.html for further information about this.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding the value in TCEFORM might not be enough, since you will need to add CSS to get the colors assigned to those new classes.

So you will at least need to have a small extension providing the items, a basic folder structure as in the usual sitepackages and the CSS embedded via `ext_tables.php` and/or `ext_localconf.php`

Comment: Yes that is a must have but not longer the biggest problem :)